# Get http web request send error in c# code

Tags: c#, json, httpwebrequest

I am using HttpWebRequest to get the response back and save stream as json document on to my drive. When I test via Postman all works fine but when I run the below C# code I get error.

**C#:**

```
            string url = "https://myapi.com/api/v1/city";
            var result = "";
            string json = string.Empty;

            HttpWebRequest hwrequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
            hwrequest.Method = "GET";
            hwrequest.Accept = "application/json";
            hwrequest.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password");

            using (var response = hwrequest.GetResponse())
            using (var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = stream.ReadToEnd();
            }

            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer
            {
                MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
            };
            json = jss.Serialize(result);
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Create(@"C:\temp\city.json")))
            {
                sw.Write(json);
            }
```

**Error:**

> The underlying connection was closed. An unexpected error occurred on
> send.

Comment: The API URL is http? the postman and the code run on the same computer? Is it the third party API?

Comment: We cant see what you sent in postman? But before you ask a question of this nature, you should have used a tool like fiddler to work out the differences in the request. Also WebRequest is a little old these days, you might consider using IHttpClientFactory

Comment: Hi @ChetanRanpariya, The api url is https. Yes, code and postman call are made from the same computer. No.

Comment: Hi @TheGeneral, If WebRequest is old what other options would best suit this need.

Comment: Dont get me wrong, its likely not the cause of your problem, please use fiddler to debug and identify your problem, its likely there is a slight difference in request

Comment: Hi @TheGeneral, Sure, I will use fiddler to debug the problem.

Comment: Hi @TheGeneral, I am not on .net core framework. Still using .NET Framework 4.6.

Answer (score 0):

That API looks like the ones displaying the json right away instead of "sending" a response.

Can you try this instead?

You will be able to use the output already in a json format any way you like after this.

```
        private string apiRead()
        {
            string xml = "";
            string remoteUrl = "https://myapi.com/api/v1/city";
            WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

            string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(webUser + ":" + webPassw)); // if you use basic authorization in base64 format
            myWebClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("Basic {0}", credentials);
            try
            {
                byte[] myDataBuffer = myWebClient.DownloadData(remoteUrl);
                xml = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myDataBuffer);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                xml = "";
            }
            

            return xml;
        }
```